# Button and Slider customizing (Size, Position, Caption size) with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have built a webinterface for my homeautomation bussystem using c, php and javascript. The function works fine, but I am having trouble in achieving the right styling for my buttons and sliders with JQuery.

What I want to do is place buttons and sliders in on "row" next to each other and be able to size and style these to be used with a regular pc browser and with my iOS devices.

1. The button sizing works fine for all my devices, but changing the button font-size withing the  section does not have an effect on the font size when viewed from a iOS device. I helped myself around this problem by setting the font-size within the html body. Is there an obvious reason for this behaviour?
2. Could somebody please point me to an example where there is a button in line with a slider and a numeric field that shows the slider value. Of course I have looked at the standard Jquery slider example but whatever combination of syntax I tried using classes to manipulate the styling I never came out with an inline slider the size, position (inline) and label that I wanted.

Below is my code as a reference.
I played with Arduinos and a Raspberry coding in c++ but obviously I am more or less without any html or javascript experience, so I would really appreciate your help!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Wipperaller</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"     href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <style>   
    body{background-color:white;}  
    button{ 
        width: 180px;
        height: 90px;
        font-size: 50px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;

        };
    myslider{
        width: 1em;
        height: 1em;
        cursor: default;}

  </style>

  <script>
    function handlerName(busCommand) 
    {
    alert(busCommand.data.msg);
    }

    function SendBusCommand(inputData) {    
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "socketclient_01.php",
      data: inputData.data,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
        $("#results").append(html); // hier wird dann der inhalt, 
                                    // den deine datei ausgibt, 
                                    //in das element mit der id results eingetragen
            } 
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").button();
        $("#SZToggle").bind("click", {destination: "11130", com: 0x35, param1: 0x00, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#SZAn").bind("click", {destination: "11130", com: 0x32, param1: 0x64, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#SZAus").bind("click", {destination: "11130", com: 0x32, param1: 0x00, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#SZKabuff").bind("click", {destination: "10206", com: 0x32, param1: 0x00, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#WZToggle").bind("click", {destination: "10106", com: 0x35, param1: 0x00, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#WZWToggle").bind("click", {destination: "10102", com: 0x35, param1: 0x00, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#EZToggle").bind("click", {destination: "11030", com: 0x35, param1: 0x00, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#EZAn").bind("click", {destination: "11030", com: 0x32, param1: 0x64, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#EZAus").bind("click", {destination: "11030", com: 0x32, param1: 0x00, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#EGAus").bind("click", {destination: "32872", com: 0x32, param1: 0x00, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#OGAus").bind("click", {destination: "32882", com: 0x32, param1: 0x00, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#AllesAus").bind("click", {destination: "32868", com: 0x32, param1: 0x00, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#KuToggle").bind("click", {destination: "10104", com: 0x35, param1: 0x00, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#AUELicht").bind("click", {destination: "10403", com: 0x35, param1: 0x00, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#AUTLicht").bind("click", {destination: "10404", com: 0x35, param1: 0x00, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#AUSteck").bind("click", {destination: "10405", com: 0x35, param1: 0x00, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#BADSLicht").bind("click", {destination: "10205", com: 0x35, param1: 0x00, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#BADDLicht").bind("click", {destination: "10302", com: 0x35, param1: 0x00, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#AlleAuf").bind("click", {destination: "32968", com: 0x32, param1: 0x64, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#AlleZu").bind("click", {destination: "32968", com: 0x32, param1: 0x00, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#EGAuf").bind("click", {destination: "32970", com: 0x32, param1: 0x64, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#EGZu").bind("click", {destination: "32970", com: 0x32, param1: 0x00, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#EGAuf").bind("click", {destination: "32972", com: 0x32, param1: 0x64, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#EGZu").bind("click", {destination: "32972", com: 0x32, param1: 0x00, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#WZJalFrontAuf").bind("click", {destination: "32974", com: 0x32, param1: 0x64, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#WZJalFrontZu").bind("click", {destination: "32974", com: 0x32, param1: 0x00, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#WZJalSeiteAuf").bind("click", {destination: "32974", com: 0x32, param1: 0x64, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
        $("#WZJalSeiteZu").bind("click", {destination: "32974", com: 0x32, param1: 0x00, param2: 0x00}, SendBusCommand);
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="gobalwrapper" style="font-size:24px">
    <h1>Bus Webfrontend</h1>
    <p class="buttons">
            <h2>Licht Gesamt</h2>
            <button id="EGAus">EG Aus</button>
            <button id="OGAus">OG Aus</button>
            <button id="AllesAus">Alles Aus</button>
    </p>
    <p class="buttons">
            <td><h2>Jalousie Gesamt</h2></td>
            <td><button id="AlleZu">Alle Zu</button></td>
            <td><button id="EGZu">EG Zu</button></td>
            <td><button id="OGZu">OG Zu</button></td>
    </p>
    <p class="buttons">
            <td><button id="AlleAuf">Alle Auf</button></td>
            <td><button id="EGAuf">EG Auf</button></td>
            <td><button id="OGAuf">OG Auf</button></td>
    </p>
    <p class="buttons">
            <h2>Licht Wohnzimmer</h2>
            <button id="WZToggle">Fluter</button>
            <button id="WZWToggle">Wand</button>
    </p>
    <p class="buttons">

            <button id="WZJalFrontZu">Front Zu</button>
            <button id="WZJalSeiteZu">Erker Zu</button>
    </p>
    <p class="buttons">         
            <button id="WZJalFrontAuf">Front Auf</button>
            <button id="WZJalSeiteAuf">Erker Auf</button>
    </p>
    <p class="buttons">
            <h2>Esszimmer</h2>
            <button id="EZToggle">Licht</button>
            <button id="EZAn">An</button>
            <button id="EZAus">Aus</button>
    </p>
    <p class="buttons">
            <h2>Küche</h2>
            <button id="KuToggle">Licht</button>
    </p>
    <p class="buttons">
            <h2>Schlafzimmer</h2>
            <button id="SZToggle">Licht</button>
            <button id="SZAn">An</button>
            <button id="SZAus">Aus</button>
            <button id="SZKabuff">Kabuff Aus</button>
            <input type="range" class="myslider" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" value="60" min="0" max="100" />
    </p>
    <p class="buttons">
            <h2>Bad</h2>
            <button id="BADDLicht">Licht</button>
            <button id="BADSLicht">Spiegel</button>
    </p>
    <p class="buttons">
            <h2>Außen</h2>
            <button id="AUELicht">Eingang</button>
            <button id="AUTLicht">Terasse</button>
            <button id="AUSteck">Steckdose</button>
    </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: create a http://jsfiddle.net/ to show an example of your problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5FLpK/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The button sizing works fine for all my devices, but changing the
>   button font-size withing the section does not have an effect on the
>   font size when viewed from a iOS device. I helped myself around this
>   problem by setting the font-size within the html body. Is there an
>   obvious reason for this behaviour?

After calling .button() method JQuery UI changes html code of button by applying few css-classes and adding span inside. If you want to change font-size - You should write something like:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-button span {
  font-size: 10px;
}
</style>
```

But better way to change look of ui elements - create your own theme or select some premade (http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

> Could somebody please point me to an example where there is a button
>   in line with a slider and a numeric field that shows the slider value.
>   Of course I have looked at the standard Jquery slider example but
>   whatever combination of syntax I tried using classes to manipulate the
>   styling I never came out with an inline slider the size, position
>   (inline) and label that I wanted.

Use display: inline-block; for button and for slider.

Comment: Thanks for the ".ui-button" hint, that solved my button problem. Now I am still left with my way too small inline slider. Is there a similar way to size the slider?

Comment: try 
.ui-slider {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
}
You can use FireBug extention in firefox to see elements code and css-classes.

Comment: .ui-slider did not work, but I haven´t installed FireBug yet.

Comment: Using FireBug´s debug console I found out, that the <input type="range" element´s classes are not changed (unlike the buttons as you explained above). Using the "myslider" class within the style block works in term of setting width, but when I try to set the height it does not really change the heigt (slider stays really thin) but instead it increases the space to its html headline. Do you have any further ideas? Always happy for any hints.

Comment: Now I see that by "slider" You mean "range". This is new html element and seems can't be easy styled (google "range element styling"). I suggest You to use http://jqueryui.com/slider/ instead. It customizable and work in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be what I was looking for. I guess my problem is that I did not really make a difference between native Jquery elements and the html stuff that gets replaced when the page gets loaded. I will check the details tomorrow ...